# Azure worker role communication query

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-virtual-machine

I am working on a project where I need my Azure worker role to communicate with couple of directories inside my Azure Virtual Machine.

Is it possible for a worker role to access files or folders which are present on Virtual Machine ?

Answer (score 1):

This [article](http://bit.ly/16STJsD)   mentions using "SMB to Share a Windows Azure Drive among multiple Role Instances". I think you can use the same principle mentioned in the article to share the folders of the the VM if it is located in the same Virtual Networking (Vnet) as your Windows Azure Roles. You can find a concrete implementation of this idea in this [project](http://bit.ly/1azllFG).

Comment: Nazik, thanks for the links, I might consider using Virtual Networking concepts.

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you can try...

1. You may use a FTP / FTP style setup to access the folder and files in your Azure Virtual Machine.
2. Make a wrapper for the file system with a web service like WebAPI.
3. Sync / store the files in Virtual Machine to Azure Storage Blob, then access the blobs from worker role.

Comment: I will try the first approach, I will update you if it works in my case.Thank you.